# How to create a Column with Value B1 with Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm doing a transformation with Pentaho kettle, and i'm getting some problems doing one step.

The scenario:

1. In my input file i have one column from where i get the company:
   COL1
2. The values i receive in COL1 is something like `"COMPANY -
   SOMENUMERSANDTEXT"`
3. I Cut the "COMPANY" part and its perfect
   (then i do a value mapper.. perfect!).. But...
4. In this file, in
   COL1, i have also some values like `"123456 - SOMENUMERSANDTEXT".`

What i want to do is do make a constant column from the first value of COL1 because is always `"COMPANY - (...) "`and its what i need.

```
+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
| COL1                        | COL2 (CUT) | COL3 (VALUE MAPPER) | COL4 (WHAT I NEED) |  |
+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
| COMPANY -SOMENUMERSANDTEXT  | COMPANY    | X                   | X                  |  |
+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
| 1234567 - SOMENUMERSANDTEXT | 1234567    | Y                   | X                  |  |
+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
| COMPANY -SOMENUMERSANDTEXT  | COMPANY    | X                   | X                  |  |
+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------------+--+
```

So my question is: Is there someone who have done something similar or have some ideias to do this?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, but why you don't use the Field splitter setting the - as your delimiter? Or you just want it to ignore when your row has numbers instead of the company name? What X is supposed to be in the second row of your example if there isn't a "COMPANY"?

Comment: Hi @astro11 , Sorry for the delay. Your suggestion is great, but the text in COL1 was like ´COMPANY - SOMENUMERSANDTEXT - SOMENUMERSANDTEXT´. The ideia was make a constant of the text ´COMPANY´ from CLO1/ROW1, in COL_X. Meanwhile, I already solve it, by using another column and other data. Thank you very much!